# An example of a sequence where {$|a_{n}|$} converges but {$a_{n}$} diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know of $(-1)^n$ but this does not diverge, it just oscillates. I am specifically looking for a sequence that diverges, but absolutely converges.

Comment: If $(|a_n|)$ converges then $(a_n)$ is bounded so it cannot diverge to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: Ah, so you're saying it can oscillate but cannot diverge.

Comment: b) Find an example such that {$|x_{n}|$} converges and ${x_{n}$ diverges. This is what the book had, So I was very confused.

Comment: Diverge means to not approach a limit, which also includes oscillating sequences.

Comment: "Diverge" means "not converge". Hence $(-1)^n$ diverges *because* it oscillates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sequence $\{|a_n|\}$ converges, then it is bounded. [You should have seen this or be able to prove this.] Then let $M= \max\{|a_n|\}$. Because $-M \leq a_n \leq M$ for all $n$, if $\{a_n\}$ diverges, then this really forces $a_n$ to 'oscillate' or just generally 'bounce around randomly' in the interval $[-M,M]$. Of course, it could do a bit of both, but you wont find an example where $a_n \to \pm \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

**Claim:** If $|a_n|\to L$, then $a_n$ is bounded.

Proof: Let $\epsilon=1$. Then there exists $N$ such that $||a_n|-L|<1$ for all $n\geq N$. Hence,
$|a_n|<L+1$ for all $n\geq N$. Let $\alpha=\max_{n<N} |a_n|$. Then for all $n,$ we have
$$
|a_n|\leq \max\{\alpha,L+1\}.
$$